# C# WinForm - How to make connection where my database is on online server which is Hostinger.ph

Tags: c#, winforms, odbc

I'm trying to connect my C# Window Form online using connection string base on the hosting provider. Here, I've stored my database info inside the online server. Whenever I update the window form, the information online will update.

Here's my connection string base on hostinger.ph given name of database,host and password

```
String constr = "server=185.28.21.131;database=u782663830_cckdb;uid=u782663830_cckus;pwd=password;Convert Zero Datetime=True"; 
// This connection string is located globally inside my project
// The name of database,userid,server and password is base on my created database inside hostinger
```

When I try to run my form, I've got the followig error that says,

```
Unable to connect to MysqlServer...
```

So, I've tried to make a connection on ODBC to check whether they meet my connection string. But I can't see my database. I see also that my port is correct. I don't know why the connection doesn't connect

[image]

Any help? Please drop your answer below. :D

Comment: Are you authorized to connect from a remote host to your database?

Comment: I don't know sir. How can I make it? :)

Comment: If you have access to a MySQL command line, try `show grants`, you should get something like `GRANT USAGE ON mydb.* TO 'myuser'@'myhost' ...` (you need to run this directly from hostinger, assuming they provide such interface).

Comment: Your provider will more than likely be able to assist you, at least more than we can. Maybe they need to explicitly grant you permission to connect ?

Comment: Sir @Holt, I can't access the MySQL command line. :(

Comment: @mark You can run SQL queries using the `phpmyadmin` interface provided by `hostinger`. Unfortunately, `hostinger` [does not grant you](http://www.hostinger.co.uk/knowledge-base/5) the privileges to use a remote connection for your database if you have a free plan.

Comment: Yes sir @Holt I see. Yeah I'm on free plan just to try this stuff. :(